# can I configure wpa_supplicant to act both as wifi and hotspot together?

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot, wpa-supplicant

I currently have a linux laptop which is connected to wifi.
I want to allow this laptop to act also as hotspot.
when I attempt to configure the hotspot the wifi:

1. the laptop losses its wifi capability (cant ping google)
2. if I connect a mobile to the hotspot- the mobile settings show that the connection is not ready (doesn't have a "V" next to it).

I used such configuration

```
network={
<regular wifi config>
}

network={
    ssid="AP-NAME"
    mode=2
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="password"
    frequency=2437
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: What frequency is your regular wi-fi network on? Does `iw phy` say that your hardware supports combined AP+station operation? Are you trying to have both modes on the same 'wlan0' interface?

Comment: valid interface combinations:
 * #{ AP } <= 1, #{ managed } <= 3, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ IBSS } <= 1, total <= 3, #channels <= 2
 if I understand correctly it means I can't act as both AP and managed?

Comment: Yes, but on separate "wlan#" interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `wlan*` interface can only work in one mode at a time, with one SSID at a time – switching wlan0 to AP mode automatically causes it to disconnect as a station from whatever SSID it was connected to.

If the device supports it, create additional network interfaces on the same wiphy (`phy0` is the Wi-Fi "hardware" device):

```
iw phy0 interface add wlan1 type managed
iw phy0 interface add wlan3 type __ap
[etc.]
```

You will probably need to run a separate wpa_supplicant instance for each interface. (Though normally `hostapd` is used for AP interfaces.)

The `#channels <= 2` *most likely* refers to one interface working in 2.4 GHz and the other in 5 GHz concurrently – it might not apply if you try to have both interfaces on the same band. In that case, you will most likely need to match your AP frequency to the existing network that you want to remain connected to.

After the AP is set up, you will need either to bridge the AP interface to its upstream network (which is what a wired AP would do, but isn't going to work when the upstream is Wi-Fi as well – search older posts for "4addr" for an explanation why) or set up IP routing and usually IPv4 NAT (masquerading) as well (which is what "hotspots" almost always do).

The latter needs an iptables `MASQUERADE` rule for NAT, the same as in regular "hotspot" setup instructions.

Comment: this answer was helpful thanks! any chance there is a link to IP forwarding part, I'm not clear on what I need to do there..